# jQuery hover fires up multiple times. No one solution helps

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, tooltip

I have popular problem with jQuery. Hover is fireing multiple times when I move a mouse on hovered element area. I tried a lot of changes between mouseenter, mouseleave, hover functions, I tried preventing event and even stopImmediatePropagation() function. No one is working. The goal is to show tooltip when hover, and hide it when mouse leaves.

My html (With TWIG. Without svg it is still not working.):

```
<div class="clock info" data-title="04:00 pm!">{% include 'icons/clock.svg.twig' %}</div>
```

My jQuery (Some code of positioning tooltip inside.):

```
$('.info').hover(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#infotitle").css("display", "block");
    var position = $(this).offset();
    $("#infotitle-text").html($(this).data('title'));
    infotitle_h = 18 + $("#infotitle-text").height();
    margin = $("#infotitle-text").width() / 2;
    $("#infotitle").stop(true,true).css("left", position.left - margin);
    $("#infotitle").stop(true,true).css("top", position.top - infotitle_h);
}, function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#infotitle").stop(true,true).css("display", "none");
});
```

Tooltip html:

```
<div id="infotitle">
    <div id="infotitle-text">Simple basic title for example.</div>
    <div id="infotitle-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Tooltip  CSS:

```
#infotitle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    display: none;
}

#infotitle-text
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    background-color: fade(@lightblue, 100%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    z-index: 100;
}

#infotitle-triangle
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: realtive;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border-color: fade(@lightblue, 100%) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Tooltip is showing and hiding generally good, but if I move a mouse on hovered element's area it is showing and hiding multiple times when it must to be visible all the time when I do it.

Please for help and thank You.

Comment: does your `$('.info').hover(function(e){` get called more than once?

Comment: [jsffidle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/d546y8bv/) it works fine to me see the demo

Comment: Now I have only one element with class ".info". In the future each element I want to show tooltip on hover will have that class too.

Comment: can you also provide your html code for the tooltip?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Yes I see it, in my opinion that code is goodbut what now... What can influe on that hover that it behave like that? Can it be connected with flexbox or  some other css? I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of the the `div.infortitle` area seats on top of the `div.info` where the mouse gets on top of the  `div.infortitle` the hover effect finishes and re enters it.

remove padding: 3px on #infortitle-text

remove margin-bottom: 10px; on #infotitle-triangle

Comment: Oh my god, really thank You... So stupid mistake, I changed it in a minute and now everything is working great.

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad way to display tooltip like that. Predefine look of tooltip, set it to display: none, and then, on hover addClass that will have display: block; property  or .show() with jquery if you must.

Changing css like you did is really, really bad practice.

Comment: I changed it for .hide() and .show() but it is still not working.

Comment: Could you make fiddle with working/bugged example? It would be much easier to see what is going on, you probably have some simple typo or something that we can't see like this.